# Angular 2 doesn't load all source files

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack

In my angular 2 project I have a few components generated by angular-cli 1.0.0-rc.0. 
So project src folder look like this:

**List:**

```
├── app
│   ├── app.component.html
│   ├── app.component.ts
│   ├── routing.module.ts
│   ├── app.module.ts
│   ├── info
│   │   ├── info.component.html
│   │   └── info.component.ts
│   ├── journal
│   │   ├── journal.component.html
│   │   └── journal.component.ts
│   ├── model
│   │   ├── entity.ts
│   │   └── user.ts
│   ├── roles
│   │   ├── roles.component.html
│   │   └── roles.component.ts
│   └── users
│       ├── users.component.html
│       ├── users.component.ts
│       └── users.service.ts
│
├── favicon.ico
├── fonts
│...
├── img
│  ...
└── index.html
```

The **src/model/user.ts** file has **User** class declaration. 
Anyway, when I launched my project I've got many errors like

> TypeError: this.currentUser.getFullName is not a function

At the Chrome DevTools on Sources I didn't find my source files from model folder, can see on [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vw5jX.png).

Why **Webpack** ignore folders, which hasn't angular components?

**AppComponent** class declaration:

```js
import {Component, OnInit} from "@angular/core";
    import {UsersService} from "./users/users.service";

    import {User} from "./model/user";

    @Component({
        selector: 'app-root',
        templateUrl: './app.component.html'
    })
    export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

        constructor(private userService: UsersService) {
        }

        currentUser: User;

        ngOnInit(): void {
            this.userService.getCurrentUser().subscribe(user => {
                this.currentUser = user;
                console.log(user);
            });
        }

        getFullName(): string {
            return this.currentUser != null ? this.currentUser.getFullName() : "";
        }

    }
```

**UsersService** class declaration:

```js
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {Http} from "@angular/http";
import "rxjs/add/operator/map";
import {Observable} from "rxjs";

import {User} from "../model/user";

@Injectable()
export class UsersService {

    private url = 'api/users'

    constructor(private http: Http) {
    }

    getCurrentUser(): Observable<User> {
        return this.http.get(`${this.url}/cu`)
            .map(response => {
                return response.json() as User;
            });
    }

    private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
        return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
    }
}
```

**User** class declaration:

```js
import {Entity} from "../model/entity";

export class User extends Entity {

    constructor(
        public id: number,
        public name: string,
        public surname: string,
        public patronimyc: string,
        public login: string
    ) {
        super(id);
    };

    getFullName():string{
        return `${this.surname} ${this.name} ${this.patronimyc}`;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you show your code? Where you use `this.currentUser.getFullName` and how you import the file?

Comment: Did you export the class/interface contained in "model"? Where do you use them? Have you a loader for "javascript" files? Indeed, I notice that your files are "js" where all the others are "ts". Maybe you don't have an appropriate loader => webpack ignores them. Although, you should see errors in webpack if it was the case.

Comment: @TheFallen There is snippet of code here [link](http://pastebin.com/gcPC0rKK)

Comment: Please add this into your question.

Comment: @ssougnez Yes, I did. I use this class on UserService and AppComponent. Both files in model folder has typescript(.ts) extenstion, I just made markdown in question description.

Comment: Post all the relevant code in the quertion: the code of the user class, or the user service, and of the user component. The bug is most probably in your code, not in Webpack.

Comment: @JBNizet, Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your service, you're doing this:

```
return response.json() as User;
```

This basically tells TypeScript: Trust me, I know that the object returned by `response.json()` is an instance of the class `User`. But it's not. `response.json()` just creates a dumb JavaScript object, which is not an instance of your class (how could Angular know about your class), and has no method other than the ones all JS objects have.

So trying to call `getFullName()` on this dumb object fails, because, as the message says, this method doesn't exist.

Comment: I think about it. There is an method that can make concrete class instance from plain js object implicit? I found this approach `let u: User = Object.assign(new User(), response.json());`, but maybe you can advice something better.